# Cumulative calculation in power BI using DAX funtion

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I want to get count that lower date value from one table comparing date value from another table.
My first table Says **NewStateTable**,

| WorkItemId | Title | ChangedDate | State | StateChangeDate | AreaPath |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27997 | logo in Code Provider Access | 16-03-2021 19:25 | New | 12-03-2021 21:53 | power |
| 28339 | Password policy needs to be updated | 12-03-2021 21:54 | New | 12-03-2021 21:54 | power |
| 28464 | Update Names of users names | 12-03-2021 21:54 | New | 12-03-2021 21:54 | power |
| 29918 | Add capturing capabilities on the Public Portal | 24-03-2021 17:27 | New | 23-02-2021 21:53 | power |
| 29919 | Refactor the code to make sure that the generated value done in a single location. | 23-02-2021 21:55 | New | 23-02-2021 21:55 | Empower |
| 29943 | Placeholder : "Provider Search Compare" needs to added on the Public Portal | 11-03-2021 17:58 | New | 23-02-2021 22:26 | power |
| 29948 | Add Document upload feature | 23-02-2021 22:51 | New | 23-02-2021 22:51 | power |

My another table Says **AllIterationTable**,

| AreaPath | IterationPath | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| power | power - Sprint1 | 08-03-2021 00:00 | 13-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - Sprint 3 | 15-03-2021 00:00 | 20-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - Migration | 22-03-2021 00:00 | 27-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - License | 29-03-2021 00:00 | 03-04-2021 00:00 |

Now I want cumulative count of all WorkItemId in custom column of AllIterationTable where NewStateTable[ChangedDate] less than AllIterationTable[StartDate]

So I applied Dax function but it won't work for me,

```
ChangedDateBeforeSprintStart = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL(NewStateTable),  NewStateTable[ChangedDate] <= AllIterationTable[StartDate]))
```

What should be my DAX function mapping two tables using Date condition and creating custom column in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
= CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(NewStateTable), FILTER(NewStateTable, NewStateTable[ChangedDate] < (AllIterationTable[StartDate]) ))
```

Comment: Thanks, Sonia. After removing ALL keywords it worked perfectly, but I already did that. Anyways thanks for posting it.